# How to set timeout globally for every ajax call in Backbone.js application?

Tags: backbone.js, asp.net-web-api, timeout

I am working with a Backbone.js framework, where I am using dot net Web API (which is created by me only). I am call the API Controller from fetch method of backbone. If this api does not respond in 30 Second i want to show some error message. Where should i set this time out period and how ?

Answer (score 1):

By default, Backbone uses `jQuery.ajax` to make its requests, which means you can set default values with [`jQuery.ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/). In your case, you would set the [timeout](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) option :

> **timeout**
>   Set a timeout (in milliseconds) for the request.

Try

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    timeout: 30000
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just manually set the timeout with all of your fetch and save calls, like so:

```
MyModelInstance.fetch({
    timeout: 6000
});
```

If you want a specific timeout globally, however, an easier thing to do is to wrap the `Backbone.sync` method when you first load Backbone.  Try this:

```
//Set the default options for all our sync calls - in this case, we're only messing with the timeout
var syncDefaultOptions = {
    timeout: 8000
};

//Save a copy of the default Backbone.sync function
var sync = Backbone.sync;

//Wrap the default Backbone.sync function with one that automatically applies our default options, but still allows them to be overwritten manually
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
    options = _.defaults(options || {}, syncDefaultOptions);
    sync(method, model, options);
};
```

Please note that the above code depends on lodash (`_.defaults()`), but you could probably replicate it without that dependency fairly easily